# No ssl client session caching in spring-boot java

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, tls1.2, resttemplate

I have built a spring-boot application that is connecting to a third party server using 2-way ssl.But, on every request a new ssl handshake is being done which increases the total response time. Upon enabling ssl logs , I found that the handshake was not being cached.

```
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
update handshake state: client_hello[1]
upcoming handshake states: server_hello[2]
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1598812487 bytes = { 209, 171, 12, 159, 240, 64, 79, 68, 213, 92, 38, 134, 30, 46, 103, 154, 107, 63, 220, 114, 125, 179, 136, 35, 18, 76, 98, 212 }
Session ID:  {}
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
update handshake state: finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
https-jsse-nio-8090-exec-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 40
https-jsse-nio-8090-exec-1, READ: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
update handshake state: change_cipher_spec
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
https-jsse-nio-8090-exec-1, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 40
check handshake state: finished[20]
update handshake state: finished[20]
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 137, 94, 123, 60, 80, 13, 84, 192, 30, 237, 123, 89 }
***
%% Didn't cache non-resumable client session: [Session-3, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
https-jsse-nio-8090-exec-1, setSoTimeout(60000) called
https-jsse-nio-8090-exec-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 844
https-jsse-nio-8090-exec-1, READ: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 504
https-jsse-nio-8090-exec-1, setSoTimeout(0) called
```

This is how I have build my Rest Template

```
        KeyStore keyStore;
        SSLContext sslContext = null;
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile(keyStoreLocation)), keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
        sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
                .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray())
                .build();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext,
                new NoopHostnameVerifier());
        Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                .register("https", sslFactory).register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.INSTANCE).build();
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(
                socketFactoryRegistry);
        poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(maxPerRoute);
        poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(maxTotal);
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext)
                .setConnectionManager(poolingHttpClientConnectionManager).build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
                client);
        httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(httpConnectTimeout);
        httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(httpConnectRequestTimeout);
        httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(httpReadTimeout);
        return new RestTemplate(httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory);
```

Kindly let me know what wrong is going here and how I can correct it. Let me know if anymore information is required from my end.

Thanks in advance!